# Abbreviated syntax for CALS package

Tags: tables, macros, cals

The `cals` package allows to create the tables with design capabilities which are available in Microsoft Word. This package is not based on `tabular` and has more bulky syntax than `tabular`. I'm try to write the macro to make the syntax more compact.

This table has been created by `cals` package:
[image: cals table sample]

Total source text is too bulky, but the begin of the table is

```
\begin{calstable}
\makeatletter
\colwidths{{10mm}{25mm}{31mm}{60mm}{24mm}{40mm}}
\def\cals@framers@width{1.5pt}
\def\cals@framecs@width{1.5pt}
\def\cals@rs@width{0.5pt}
```

Suppose we're going to replace this by **tabbegin** macro:

```
\newcommand{\tabbegin}{
\makeatletter
\colwidths{{10mm}{25mm}{31mm}{60mm}{24mm}{40mm}}
\def\cals@framers@width{1.5pt}
\def\cals@framecs@width{1.5pt}
\def\cals@rs@width{0.5pt}}
```

However, if to do this, the tabular frame will be lost. 
What is the reason?

The MVE includes only first five rows of the table which has been represented on the picture, but it's enough. Please use XeLaTeX to compile the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[BoldFont]{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{MS PMincho}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\newfontfamily\russianfont{Calibri}

% --- 振り仮名 ---------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{ruby}
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{-0.1ex}

\usepackage{cals}

\oddsidemargin=-10.4mm
\topmargin=-35mm
\textwidth=190mm
\textheight=275mm

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{ookiikanji}{rgb}{0.76,0.84,0.61}
\definecolor{onyomi}{rgb}{0.84,0.89,0.74}
\definecolor{kunyomi}{rgb}{0.92,0.95,0.87}

\newcommand{\tabbegin}{
\makeatletter
\colwidths{{10mm}{25mm}{31mm}{60mm}{24mm}{40mm}}
\def\cals@framers@width{1.5pt}
\def\cals@framecs@width{1.5pt}
\def\cals@rs@width{0.5pt}}


\begin{document}
\begin{calstable}
\tabbegin
% === 日 =================
% --- 音読み -------------    
% --- ニチ
\brow \def\cals@bgcolor{ookiikanji}
\nullcell{ltr} \def\cals@borderL{0.75pt} \alignL\def\cals@bgcolor{onyomi}
\alignL\cell{\vfil \fontsize{12}{1} 日} \let\cals@borderL=\relax
\alignL\cell{\vfil \fontsize{11}{1} ニチ}
\alignL\cell{\vfil \fontsize{10}{1}\itshape день; солнце; Япония, японский} \def\cals@borderL{0.75pt}
\alignC\cell{\vfil \fontsize{12}{1} \ruby{日常}{にちじょう}の} \let\cals@borderL=\relax
\alignL\cell{\vfil \fontsize{10}{1}\itshape  повседневный, обычный} \erow \def\cals@rs@width{0.5pt}
% --- ニ
\brow \def\cals@bgcolor{ookiikanji}
\nullcell{lr} \def\cals@borderL{0.75pt} \alignL\def\cals@bgcolor{onyomi}
\alignL\cell{\vfil \fontsize{12}{1} 日} \let\cals@borderL=\relax
\alignL\cell{\vfil \fontsize{11}{1} ニ}
\alignL\cell{\vfil \fontsize{10}{1}\itshape день; солнце; Япония, японский} \def\cals@borderL{0.75pt}
\alignC\cell{\vfil \fontsize{12}{1} \ruby{日本}{にほん}} \let\cals@borderL=\relax
\alignL\cell{\vfil \fontsize{10}{1}\itshape Япония} \erow
% --- ジツ
\brow \def\cals@bgcolor{ookiikanji}
\nullcell{lr} \def\cals@borderL{0.75pt} \alignL\def\cals@bgcolor{onyomi}
\alignL\cell{\vfil \fontsize{12}{1} 日} \let\cals@borderL=\relax
\alignL\cell{\vfil \fontsize{11}{1} ジツ}
\alignL\cell{\vfil \fontsize{10}{1}\itshape день; солнце; Япония, японский} \def\cals@borderL{0.75pt}
\alignC\cell{\vfil \fontsize{12}{1} \ruby{末日}{まつじつ}} \let\cals@borderL=\relax
\alignL\cell{\vfil \fontsize{10}{1}\itshape последний день} \erow \def\cals@rs@width{0.75pt}
% --- 訓読み -------------    
% --- ひ/び
\brow \def\cals@bgcolor{ookiikanji}
\nullcell{lr} \def\cals@borderL{0.75pt} \def\cals@bgcolor{kunyomi}
\alignL\cell{\vfil \fontsize{12}{1} 日} \let\cals@borderL=\relax
\alignL\cell{\vfil \fontsize{11}{1} ひ/び}
\alignL\cell{\vfil \fontsize{10}{1}\itshape день; солнце} \def\cals@borderL{0.75pt}
\alignC\cell{\vfil \fontsize{12}{1} \ruby{日切}{ひぎ}り} \let\cals@borderL=\relax
\alignL\cell{\vfil \fontsize{10}{1}\itshape расчёт по дням, график} \erow \def\cals@rs@width{0.5pt}
% --- が
\brow \def\cals@bgcolor{ookiikanji}
\nullcell{lrb}\alignC\spancontent{\vfil \fontsize{20}{1}\bfseries 日} \def\cals@borderL{0.75pt} \def\cals@bgcolor{kunyomi}
\alignL\cell{\vfil \fontsize{12}{1} 日} \let\cals@borderL=\relax
\alignL\cell{\vfil \fontsize{11}{1} か}
\alignL\cell{\vfil \fontsize{10}{1}\itshape день (соч.)} \def\cals@borderL{0.75pt}
\alignC\cell{\vfil \fontsize{12}{1} \ruby{二日}{ふつか}} \let\cals@borderL=\relax
\alignL\cell{\vfil \fontsize{10}{1}\itshape 2 дня} \erow \def\cals@rs@width{1pt}
\makeatother
\end{calstable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to put the `\makeatletter` *outside* the macro definition. So try `\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tabbegin}{
\colwidths{{10mm}{25mm}{31mm}{60mm}{24mm}{40mm}}
\def\cals@framers@width{1.5pt}
\def\cals@framecs@width{1.5pt}
\def\cals@rs@width{0.5pt}}`